Why won’t Ubuntu make it past the boot messages screen?
After trying to install dependencies for FUSE (and forgetting for an hour and a half that apt install exists) I restarted my PC and it no longer boots on any kernel. I attached a photo of what I get when I try to boot. Is it possible that my screwing around caused something to break? If so, how do I fix it?


Impossible to answer. That image only shows the SUCCESFULL command (ie. see the OK at the last line). Please see if you can enter a terminal (control alt f1) and then investigate /var/log/, dmesg, and journalctl for error notices after the deluge service has started.

Search for "Wait until snapd is fully seeded" on this site. The problem might be either a lack of space, or an old bug in snapd where snapd was waiting for a sufficient amount of random input before moving on. As incredible as it sounds, moving the mouse around a bit at this point would speed the boot process up. However, that bug has long been repaired. What Ubuntu version are you running?

More details on your "screwing around" would be helpful.

I am running the latest version of Ubuntu, and my screwing around was trying to compile FUSE and all of its dependencies from source, beacuse I didn’t realize I could just use apt install.
